# Xcode 6 - Syntax highlight / completion not working

Tags: ios, xcode, syntax, xcode6, highlight

After one day my code loses its highlight / completion again in xCode 6.

As always, I tried to Organizer > Projects > and Delete Derived Data.
Which did not work in Xcode 6, even after it finish to index everything.

I tried to uninstall and install 3 times - and its still coming back after some time.

I really can't find why Xcode loses it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to compile? This may happen when there is an error in the code.

Comment: If you have a developer account you could try the latest beta, I was having the same problem (No errors or warnings on compilation), and don't with the latest beta.

Comment: Yes, I tried to compile again and again but its still not working for some unknown reason.

Comment: Should i install xcode 6.1 beta ?

Comment: Well that's worked!
Xcode 6.1 beta doing it well :)
Thank you very much.

Comment: This issue still persists in Xcode 6.1.1 (no beta). Syntax highlighting sometimes works partially, only.

Answer (score 6):

Syntax highlighting and code completion can sometimes only work on part of the file too, and it happens during the editing or on a random basis.

I fix this by cleaning the project... not a sexy solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in some Xcode versions, I have it on Xcode 6.4 and the only solution I found is to open Editor menu -> Syntax coloring -> Choose None
then Editor menu -> Syntax coloring -> Default for filetype.

PS: cleaning the project didn't solve the problem for me.